# How do I customize WordPress's wp_nav_menu function

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress site and the top nav is generated by:

`<?php wp_nav_menu(array('container_class' => 'nav', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'theme_location' => 'top_nav')); ?>`

And it picks up the nav items from the defined list in the wp_admin.

Thing is, I want each item to have extra, conditional, CSS on it. Specifically,

1) on hover, I want the text to color up, as well as a same-colored line to appear.

2) When I'm in a certain area (determined by slug) I want that menu item to stay colored. i.e.: active

3) Each of the menu items have different colors - it's not universal across the nav.

Obviously, the CSS behind this is simple. My question is how to keep the "black box" aspect of using wp_nav_menu() but still be able to put all that conditional code in the nav.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: use css selectors in your stylesheet `nth-of-type()` can select individual elements if no id exists

Comment: I know how nth-of-type() works, but I'm not sure how that plays into this. Could you please elaborate on what you are trying to suggest?

Comment: all the walker does is output the html in the end, if you look at the final result there are ul li 's  so for your 3rd  critera : `ul li:nth-of-type(3){background: black;}` will color your 3rd li for you. (ps add more specific selectors than ul li, eg nav ul li), same goes for hover, `ul li:hover`

Comment: I see where  you're going with that. Interesting. Is there a way to make one of the nav items active based on the page you're on? In other words, my six nav items correspond to six categories. Is there a way to tell wp_nav_menu to check to see if the nav item matches the category and, if so, add an active class?

Comment: I'm close. I know that the current one has an added class of `current-menu-item` but the following doesn't work. I'm working on it:

`.responsiveSelectContainer ul li:nth-child(1).current-menu-item{
    border-bottom: solid 3px #107B7E;
    color: #107B7E !important;
}`

Comment: you need a space, but there is no need for specifity here, the selector is unique enough- `.current-menu-item{}`

Comment: I need the specificity since depending on which `li` is the current one, the CSS will change. I'm not applying the same CSS to current-menu-item regardless of where it shows up.

Comment: ah rite... , check your html to see where it lies, at the moment you are selecting the first child of every li that have the class current menu item, is this correct?

Comment: Thank you David! Your comment made me realize that I was editing the wrong element! I needed to edit the a inside the selected li!  I just tried it and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Using wp_nav_menu() : custom walker you can customized own way menu item
Example:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu

Comment: As much as I appreciate that link, my head is spinning trying to understand it! :(